# Xubuntu: how to remove the printer icon?

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, xfce, xfce-panel

I'm on Xubuntu 13.10 64 bit, I printed something, now the printer icon is still up there next to the battery icon, I solve the problem by logging out and in. But I want a better solution for next time that does not require me to log out.

EDIT: I'm having the same problem. As requested, here is a screenshot:

[image]

When I try to click (left or right) on the printer icon, nothing happens. Only logging out and back in again clears it away.

Comment: If it's a bug, I'll report it on Launchpad

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, below is how I solved it.

Just right click on the icon, and then click Hide.  That will hide the icon, and it won't show again.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: This issue happened few hours ago, as I recall I couldn't right click or click, also the icon isn't exactly the same, there was a red dote or something on it

Comment: @Fischer When this happens again, make a screenshot and post it in the question.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. the icon cannot be clicked (right or left). It only disappears when I logout/login or restart... I am running 14.04

Comment: I can confirm that, like @user1291235, that since upgrading to 14.04, I also don't see a menu with either or right or left click to the icon, and only a logout/login or restart removes it.

Answer (score 1):

By doing the above procedure , only the icon is gone . To actually stop it from running in background , double click on the icon and a window will open . Now close all the left over print jobs ( probably left over commands or unsuccessful print commands ) . Then the icon will be gone and the printing mechanism is actually closed .

Answer (score 0):

If the icon appears due to print jobs got stuck then you can follow this

firstly click on the printer icon and clear/cancel any print jobs that are stuck, now kill the "indicator-printers-service" from terminal using following commands

- ps -ef | grep indicator-printers-service
- kill $pid (note the pid from above command's output)

this should hopefully remove the icon